# Cuál es el significado de Cordell en español?

Tags: traducción, significado

En la canción Cordell de The Cranberries se usa mucho esta palabra. En la canción se usa referenciando a Denny Cordell.

Antes de conocer esto vi que se usaba también para referirse a personas que son "maravillosas", esto de http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Cordell.

Dado que el significado que le otorgan a esta palabra variaba mucho en ese sitio, cual es la traducción más apropiada de esta palabra?

Pd: Esta pregunta fue creada con otra inteción, pero al ser respondida por @Rodrigo, decidí editarla y así conocer el significado de esta palabra fuera de la canción de The Cranberries

Comment: Al margen de tu pregunta, que va por otro lado, la canción de Cranberries se refiere a este señor: [Denny Cordell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denny_Cordell)

Comment: No es que la [entrada de wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cordell) aporte mucho más, pero viendo la de Urban dictionary, me inclino por pensar que "Cordell" es simplemente un nombre propio y que Urban dictionary es una fuente mucho menos fiable de lo que pensaba. No tiene ningún sentido esa interpretación y no se recoge en ningún otro lado. Es como si yo editase la entrada de "Diego" en el Urban dictionary para decir que los "diegos" son gente maravillosa que merece gobernar el mundo.

Comment: Por cierto, aporto [un enlace a la letra de la canción](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/cranberries/cordell.html) por si el uso en ese contexto ayuda a alguien a proporcionar una buena respuesta. "**Cordell**, /
Time will tell, /
They say that you've passed away, /
And I hope you've gone to a better place. /
Time will tell, /
Time will tell, /
We all will depart and decay, /
And we all will return to a better place. /
**Cordell [X7]**"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no tiene que ver con el idioma español. Como se vio en los comentarios, Cordell es el apellido de una persona y, por tanto, intraducible.